# How to add trix.css when it is removed after pruning?

Tags: django, angularjs, docker, backend

After pruning with the command "docker system prune -a" nodejs wont build anymore beacuse trix.css is missing. I am assuming this was probably deleted while pruning. How can I resolve this error (see the error below)? Why is it not created again while building the container again since the file is in the docker file.

```
Required path doesn't exist: /code/bower_components/trix/dist/trix.css trix
[13:57:39] 'vendorcss' errored after 1.63 ms
[13:57:39] Error: Promise rejected without Error
at Domain.onError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/async-done/index.js:49:15)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Domain.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Domain._errorHandler (domain.js:134:21)
at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:375:33)
[13:57:39] 'staging' errored after 41 ms
ERROR: Service 'nodejs' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c gulp staging' returned a non- 
zero code: 1
```

Usually I use this command : "sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-staging.yml build nodejs" when I want to build the container again. I am very new to this and would be greatfull for some help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the case:

The issue exists because `trix.css` was removed in the latest version. It has nothing to do with `docker system prune` as far as I understand.

You can compare the two versions here: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/compare/1.3.1...v2.0.0

Basically, in order to fix this issue, you need to do

```
yarn install
yarn build
```

inside `bower_components`. This is suggested in the official updated README of the trix repository: https://github.com/basecamp/trix.

Once done with that, you will have `trix.css` and `trix.umd.min.js` files for your perusal.

Comment: Thank you! Knowing that the problem is the version helped me. The only thing is how do I build with yarn inside bower? I have added the previous version of trix in bower.json file, this creates the trix css file inside that folder for now and the project builds great. But it is just a bad practise doing it like this. So how do I build with yarn inside the bower_components?